# Calculating one cell from dbf table to another cell in same table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor

- Am absolutely new to python programming for ArcGIS.
  How do I calculate one cell from one field in DBF table into another cell in another field in same table?

[image: screenshot of attribute table to update]

Here is what I've got that doesn't work:

```
import arcpy 
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("S2_merge1",["Name1"])
cursor1 = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("S2_merge1",["Name5"])
for row in cursor1:
   row[1]=cursor
   cursor1.updateRow([row])
```

Comment: Part of the issue is semantics: Tables *don't* have "cells" -- they have "rows" and "columns" (dBase is calls them "records" and "fields"). If you use spreadsheet terminology to interact with a database model, your Python coding is going to just be that much more difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track [using an `UpdateCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/de/help/main/10.2/index.html#/na/018w00000014000000/). However, both the source and target fields need to be *in the same cursor* — `cursor1` can't see `cursor`.

Keep both fields within the same cursor.

```
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("S2_merge1", ["Name1","Name5"])
for row in cursor:
    row[1] = row[0]
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Also note [the index of a list starts at 0, not 1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm). In the list of fields that is used in `cursor`, `Name1` is the first at position `0`, and `Name5` is second at position `1`. You may be aware of this, but I wanted to make it clear based on the code used in your question :)

---

Be aware that this will update *all the rows in the table* `S2_merge1`. If you want to update *only a single row* (or subset of rows), then you should include a `where_clause` when defining the cursor. This should be a familiar SQL definition query...

```
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("S2_merge1", ["Name1", "Name5"], 'FID = 1')
```